# Check Variables value without knowing Name PHP

Tags: php

I have a big script and facing a problem .... leak in memory (php)

I want to close all open variables to fix that but i relay cant do that because script is old and long ....

So i was thinking to find a way to close all variables at the end of page by finding which variables are open and then close them.

like this example for post variables

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
$key = Null;
echo "$key is $value";
```

i there a way to find all open variables on a page

```
Ex  
$a = 20;
$b = 'go';
$c = 55;

$a = null;

Now Find open variables and close them
```

Comment: If I were you I would check where the specific leak is coming from, and fix that problem. Bugfixing can be tedious and long slow work. but sometimes it has to be done

Comment: Hi. The two places that i know lead to memory leak is if you  define a class inside other class. And if you not free the array that you get from DB. use unset($yourArray); and if you use classes  gc_collect_cycles(), if you use multythreading check that you don't have a Zombies process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find open variables: [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

To free them: [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

To make get_defined_vars output readable:

```
$varzzz = get_defined_vars();
echo ("<pre>");
print_r($varzzz);
echo ("</pre>");
```

When you'll be unsetting your variables, don't treat the "_.*" keys.